# Divide every number in every column by 1000 in R

Tags: r

I would like to divide every number in all columns by 1000. I would like to omit the row header and the 1st column from this function.

I have tried this code:

```
 TEST2=(TEST[2:503,]/(1000))
```

But it is not what I am looking for. My dataframe has 503 columns.

Comment: Mind the ,. Try `TEST[, 2:503]`

Comment: You try to access rows, use instead  `TEST2=(TEST[,2:503]/(1000))`

Comment: Or: `newTest <- TEST[, -1]/1000  ## negative indexing of columns.` Data.frames require rownames but matrices do not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is `TEST` a dataframe? In that case, the row header won't be divided by 1000. To choose all columns except the first, use an index in `j` to select all columns but the first? e.g.

```
TEST[, 2:ncol(TEST)]/1000 # selects every row and 2nd to last columns
# same thing
TEST[, -1]/1000 # selects every row and every but the 1st column
```

Or you can select columns by name, etc (you select columns just like how you are selecting rows at the moment).

Probably  take a look at `?'['` to learn how to select particular rows and columns.

Comment: If you don't assign it to some name it will not remain in the workspace. (I know mc knows this but I'm not sure that userX knows this,)

Comment: How can I bind the first column with the results of the /1000. I can get all the values divided, but I still would like my column 1 in the dataframe. The code I have now deletes it

Comment: So just store it and then add that column in. e.g. `TEST2 <- TEST....; TEST2$Column1 <- Test1$Column1`?